# Perl : empty variable while using eval in a thread

Tags: multithreading, perl, eval

I'm facing an issue while updating my project from perl 5.8.8 to perl 5.18.2.
I've reduced the problem to the followinig example :

```
use threads;

my $key = "abcdef";

print "test1 key = $key.\n";

my $thr = threads->create(sub {
    eval "print \"test2 key = \$key.\n\";";
}); 

$thr->join();
```

In perl 5.8.8, this gives the correct output :

```
test1 key = abcdef.
test2 key = abcdef.
```

But with perl 5.18.2, I have :

```
test1 key = abcdef.
test2 key = .
```

I've tried other perl versions, and the problem seems to have appeared with the 5.14.0 release.
I'm looking for the best way to correct this problem, as well as explanation about this modification of perl beaviour.

I've found a few alternatives, but none of them seem good for me :

- using "our $key" instead of "my $key"; but this make the variable "more public"
- adding "my $toto = $key;" before the eval line (while still using $key in the eval line); in fact doing something (print, affectation, use, ...) with $key before the eval line seems to solve the problem. But the added line is useless for the function.

Using $key instead of \$key in the eval command is not a solution for me since in the real program I will be handling much more complex structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not related to threads. See a similar [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=822768) thread. To create a closure, the compiler needs to know a variable will be used. You can just mention the variable in the sub to be closed over:

```
my $thr = threads->create(sub {
    $key;  # Create a closure.
    eval "print \"test2 key = \$key.\n\";";
});
```

To see a similar non-threaded situation, just create a scope:

```
my $sub = do {
    my $key = "abcdef";
    print "test1 key = $key.\n";
    sub {
        $key; # <-- Comment this line to get no value.
        eval "print \"test2 key = \$key.\n\";";
    }
};

$sub->();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Do you know why it was working with perl 5.8.8 without adding the mention to the variable ?

Comment: You want to know why 5.8.8 captured variables it didn't need? Because that's how it was coded.

Comment: @ikegami: Sounds familiar :)

Comment: This was a bug found by a number of people, myself included, that was eventually fixed in 5.14. It was causing closures to capture too much of their outer scope, which sometimes had bad consequences for reference counting and memory reclamation.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has two functions named `eval`.

- `eval EXPR` parses and executes Perl code.
- `eval BLOCK` is an exception trap. This is often called `try` in other languages.

The use of the proper function will resolve your problem since it doesn't try to use variables that no longer exist.